# How to be recognized on Google for date-specific content

Tags: date, seo

Let's assume we're writing an article about an event which takes place on March 11th, for example the Champions League soccer match between Atletico and Milan.

The article is published on March 9th and edited on March 10th.

What should the page title and metadata be in order for Google to recognize we're talking about that particular event and not the same match which was played eight months ago? If someone googles for "11.3. Atletico-Milan" or "2014/3/11 Atletico-Milan", what is the best way for an article being recognized on Google as belonging to that date?

The question may be a bit vague but I'm uncertain how does Google process dates, and the question here is about the general concept of Google actually connecting the article to a specific date. Which date formatting to use (audience is European in this case and the date would be 11.3.2014.), where to put the date (title, body, metadata...), mention the date once or multiple times?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Well it does have the SEO tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `microdata`, this is the preferred way for search engines. Have a look at the [Event schema](http://schema.org/Event) over at Schema.org.

You'll need to include that microdata in your article when talking about the event. Make sure you make use of the `startDate` property.

Comment: Schema.org can be used with Microdata, RDFa or JSON-LD, but not with Microformats.

Comment: You're right, I meant microdata.